# Empty bin,libs,src folders after creating Android project using Javafx android-tools

Tags: java, android, gradle, javafx, javafxports

After creating an Android project using Javafx android-tools, the folders bin, libs, and src were empty! I followed this tutorial: [android / Building and deploying JavaFX Applications](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/android/wiki/Building%20and%20deploying%20JavaFX%20Applications).

Have I missed something? Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that tutorial is quite old... Now you can just use the last plugin they have realeased.

Go to [Getting Started](http://javafxports.org/page/Getting_Started) site, and check you have everything in place. Basically, you will need:

- JDK8u40 early access [release](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html) installed, JAVA_HOME should be set with the JDK path.
- [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) 2.2.1 installed
- Android [SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools)
- Android Build Tools 21.1.1 using SDK Manager.
- Gradle Plugin for NetBeans or your IDE (optional)
- And the plugin which is a 'build.gradle' file.

**build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:javafxmobile-plugin:1.0.0-rc3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'javafxmobile'

mainClassName='org.javafxports.android.MainJavaFX'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

jfxmobile {
    android {
        applicationPackage = 'org.javafxports.android'
        androidSdk = file ('<your path to android sdk>')
    }
}
```

You can try the Ensemble 8 project that you can download from [here](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin-ensemble) or clone the project, and see for yourself how easy it is to port this application to Android.

You can create the apk as easy as typing on command line:

```
gradlew android
```

or this to create the apk and install it on your android device if you have it connected:

```
gradlew androidInstall
```

Once you have tested it, you will want to create your own project. So now you can create new projects with the Gradle plugin. Assuming you use NetBeans, you can create first a root project, and then add an empty subproject. On this subproject you can add all your JavaFX sources and you should override the default gradle.build file with the one shown above, adapting the path to your packages.

You will need the gradlew files and folder from the ensemble project, or if you have gradle on your path, then you can build the apk with the same commands, but using `gradle android`.

**Important considerations**

The plugin works with the last JDK8 8u40, but it doesn't support all Java 8 features (Streams and Optional), while it supports Lambdas. On the contrary, it supports mainly all the JavaFX 8 features.

It's in working progress, so some issues may not been solved yet, and you can [report](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/issues?status=new&status=open) any problem you may have.

Comment: Thank you Sir, Im currently using Windows XP, I think this wont work on xp. right?

Comment: For starters, you need JDK 8u40, with no official support for XP, though it seems it can be installed. Do you have the last version 8u31 installed?

Comment: Im, currently using Netbeans 7.2, is it okay?

Comment: I compiled my javafx project using netbeans with jdk 8, is it okay or should I compile it with jdk 7?

Comment: I can't tell if it will work with your tools. In case you have any problem, please update your question with relevant details (tools you are using, project configuration, relevant code, exceptions, ...) so we can help you.

Comment: Is it okay to use **JDK8u45** instead of **JDK8u40**?

Comment: Sure, you can use `javafxportsVersion` on build.gradle to select which version of javafxports to use. In fact you can already use 8u60. Anyway, don't open a question in the comments of an old one...