# Creating Android project using Javafx android-tools (Empty folders)

Tags: java, javafx, javafxports

I have a problem encountered during the creation of android project using Javafx build-tools.

I followed this tutorial already [Empty bin,libs,src folders after creating Android project using Javafx android-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28491131/empty-bin-libs-src-folders-after-creating-android-project-using-javafx-android-t), but it didnt worked for me.

I'm using Windows7 as my OS.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Edit your question and tell us what tools are you using (sdk versions), and where is the problem (exceptions), otherwise is impossible for anyone to help you.

Comment: I used netbeans 8.0, intalling a gradle plugin to it. I used the Ensemble sample and perform an assembleDebug but and error was thrown:

Comment: * What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':createDebugMainDexClassList'.
> failed to find Build Tools revision 21.1.1

Comment: Have you installed Android Build Tools? Use SDK Manager and install 21.1.1 and 21.1.2, and try again

Comment: Yes sir, I installed 21.1.2 already!

Comment: But it complains because it's looking for a previous version (21.1.1), so you need to install that as well

Comment: But right now, Im currently installing 21.1.1... still downloading...

Comment: Sir, it worked, but unfortunately another error occured:                Execution failed for task ':android:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
 C:\AndroidSDK\build-tools\21.1.1\dx.bat -JXmx2g --dex --no-optimize --core-library --output C:\FXSamples\MultiProject\android\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\FXSamples\MultiProject\android\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt