# JavaFX to Android (com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException)

Tags: java, android, javafx, javafx-8

Im on my way to deploy my Javafx application to Android, I followed the tutorial [Empty bin,libs,src folders after creating Android project using Javafx android-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28491131/empty-bin-libs-src-folders-after-creating-android-project-using-javafx-android-t), I used the Ensemble sample from dalvik-sdk, but after performing assembleDebug, an error was thrown:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':android:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run  command:
C:\AndroidSDK\build-tools\21.1.1\dx.bat -JXmx2g --dex --no-optimize --core-library --output     C:\FXSamples\MultiProject\android\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-   list=C:\FXSamples\MultiProject\android\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that JVM 1.8 u40 is configured in your machine.

[check here](http://blog.sibvisions.com/2015/04/08/jvx-javafx-ui-with-javafxports/)

Comment: This should be comment.