# Configured androidSdk is invalid (Deploying JavaFX to Android)

Tags: java, android, javafx-8

I developed a small JavaFX Application and I want to run it in my Android Phone. I followed the tutorial [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28491131/empty-bin-libs-src-folders-after-creating-android-project-using-javafx-android-t), unfortunately, after invoking `gradlew androidinstall`, an error shows up. It says `Configured androidSdk is invalid`. I swear the android directory is set to right path which is `C:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows`(Please see the directory image below).

**Error Message:**

```
SigningConfig{name=debug, storeFile=C:\Documents and Settings\DQ\.android\debug.keystore, storePassword=android, keyAlias=AndroidDebugKey, keyPassword=android, storeType=C:\Documents and Settings\DQ\.android\debug.keystore}

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Configured androidSdk is invalid: C:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -- option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.672 secs
```

**Directory Screenshot:**

[image]

I also tried `C:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows\tools`, but it didn't worked!

Any Idea?

**build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.0-b8'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

mainClassName = 'main.java.Main'
version = '8u40'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

jfxmobile {
    android {
        applicationPackage = 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'
    }
 }
```

Comment: @José Pereda, Sir, do you have any idea about this error?

Comment: You still use win XP ?! Have you tried it on a ,at least win 7 machine?  Did you try to execute with admin rights or place it to D: ?

Comment: Okay, I will try your suggestion Sir. Thank you very much. I'll give you a feedback soon, after the testing.. :)

Comment: I'm not sure about Win XP, as @simonides has pointed out. Anyway, try to post your `build.gradle` file and how you set `androidSDK`.

Comment: @José Pereda, please see the updated codes

Comment: Could you post how and where do you set `androidSDK` variable? Check [this](http://javafxports.org/page/Getting_Started), prerequisites, step 3. Also be aware that `applicationPackage` should refer to your package `main.java`.

Comment: I created ANDROID_HOME in the Environment Variables. I also modified the applicationPackage to main.java, still didn't work.

Comment: @José Pereda, Sir, Im using JDK8u45 instead of JDK8u40. Is it okay?

Comment: Yes, that's not a problem. I suggest you creating this property `ANDROID_HOME=C:/Program Files/android-sdk-windows` on the `gradle.properties` file under <user>/.gradle folder.

Comment: @José Pereda, you mean a Property file? A file with a .property extension?

Comment: Yes, C:\<user>\.gradle\gradle.properties

Comment: @José Pereda, Sir, unfortunately, it didn't worked! Thanks. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the sdk folder there is no build-tools folder. You should run `tools/android` and install Android SDK Build-tools

[image]

Comment: in my case buid-tools are all installed , but am getting the same error!! what shall i do?